# WebView rendering error

Tags: android, android-webview, openlayers-3

I'm developing a very simple Android application.
The application is just a webview linked to [this OpenLayers3 docs](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/examples/popup.html).

There is really nothing special in the application. It is just a WebView,
but I get this rendering error when I open a popup:

[image]

This happen on a Honor7.
I noticed that if I disable the hardware acceleration the problem does **not** persist but in this way the performances are very poor.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is this happening with the latest ol3 version(3.15)?? If your try it with ol3 version 3.13 do you have the same result?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the latest update to Android System Web View, that comes automatically from Google Play. If you uninstall the update, it helps. It is of course not a really good solution((((